# Reset \psset within a pspicture environment

Tags: pstricks

How can I invalidate a style that was created using a `\psset` comand within a `pspicture` environment?

Take the following MWE, which compiles with XeLaTeX:

I would like to invalidate the current style after the middle black circle is drawn so that the red circle at the bottom has the same `linewidth` as the blue circle at the top.

[image: three circles]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(2,4)
    % Set new style
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    % Draw top circle
    \pscircle(1,3){1}
    % Set new style
    \psset{linewidth=4pt, linecolor=black}
    % Draw middle circle
    \pscircle(1,2){1}

    % Invalidate current style here

    % Set new style
    \psset{linecolor=red} % linewidth is kept at 4pt!
    % Draw bottom circle
    \pscircle(1,1){1}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very simple: `\psset{linecolor=red, linewidth=0.8pt}`. 0.8pt is the default value of  the length `\pslinewidth`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot Bernard! Are the default values of `pstricks` documented somewhere?

Comment: For pstricks-base, they're given with the definition of the parameters. For instance, `linewidth` default is in `pst-user.pdf`, §5, p. 8. For other packages, they generally have a list of parameters defined by the extension, with the default, at the end of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group

```
{% begin a group 
    % Set new local style
    \psset{linewidth=4pt, linecolor=black}
    % Draw middle circle
    \pscircle(1,2){1}
}% end the group
```

Then the settings are local.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(2,4)
    % Set new style
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    % Draw top circle
    \pscircle(1,3){1}

    {% begin a group
        % Set new local style
        \psset{linewidth=4pt, linecolor=black}
        % Draw middle circle
        \pscircle(1,2){1}
    }% end the group

    % Set new style
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    % Draw bottom circle
    \pscircle(1,1){1}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Or you use the optional argument of `\pscircle`:

```
% Draw middle circle with new style
\pscircle[linewidth=4pt, linecolor=black](1,2){1}
```

Comment: That's great! I didn't know you could define groups with curly brackets. So simple. Using the optional arguments of `\pscircle` is a very elegant approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

use always local settings without `\psset` which makes more or less only sense for global settings:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(2,4)
    \pscircle[linecolor=blue](1,3){1}
    \pscircle[linewidth=4pt](1,2){1}
    \pscircle[linecolor=red](1,1){1}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```